# Modifying an parameter any of URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change any parameter is available from a URL using Javascript

Ex:
   http://demo.com/admin/?admin-page=faq&kw=123
=> http://demo.com/admin/?admin-page=faq&kw=123456

I have tried several ways but have not achieved the desired results you can help me solve it?

Comment: *"I have tried several ways"* Like what? *"...but have not achieved the desired results."* In what way? What happened instead of what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

The portion of the URL you're changing is the *query string*, which is available from the `location.search` property. It's a `&`-separated series of URI-encoded `key=value` pairs.

You can split it up like this:

```
var search = location.search.charAt(0) === '?' ? location.search.substring(1) : location.search;
var pairs = search.split('&').map(function(pair) {
    return pair.split('=');
});
```

Then search through `pairs` looking for the one where `pair[0]` is `kw` and replace its value:

```
pairs.some(function(pair) {
    if (pair[0] === 'kw') {
        pair[1] = encodeURIComponent(yourNewValue);
        return true;
    }
});
```

(`Array#some` loops through the entries of an array and stops when you return `true` from the callback.)

Then assign the result:

```
location.search = '?' + pairs.join('&');
```

...which will load the page with the new query string in the window.

---

Side note: The above uses two features of arrays that are new as of ES5. Both are "shimmable" so if you need to support IE8, you'll want an ES5 shim. (Searching for "es5 shim" will give you options.)

Comment: FYI - I tried your `map` code `array[index] = pair.split('=');`, but this did not work for me (Chrome v33), since `pairs[0]` and `pairs[1]` were set to `undefined`. Instead I had to use `return pair.split('=');` which did the trick.

Comment: @JasonEvans: Ah, yes, I did a combination of two things there. Either use `map` and return the split, or use `forEach` (and create the array separately). Was typing too fast. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand correctly, you just want to update an URL. Then you just have to edit it.

With jQuery :

```
$("#myLink").attr("href", myNewHref);
```

Pure Javascript :

```
myLink.href = myNewHref;
```

Where `myNewHref` can be update using string manipulation such `split` function or Regex to get the first part of your URL (http://demo.com/admin/) and then getting parameters after the character '?'.